# download file from google drive

Tags: vba, download, google-drive-api

I am trying to donwload a file from google drive. I check for these two examples but no one works for me:

```
  Sub DownloadPDF()
Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim MyFile As String
Dim WHTTP As Object

On Error Resume Next
    Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

MyFile = "https://docs.google.com/a/dink.eu/file/d/0B2P4BoDG6mdejjesiEEFMNHN0cFU/edit?usp=sharing"

WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
WHTTP.send
FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

If Dir("C:\MyDownloads", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir "C:\MyDownloads"

FileNum = FreeFile
Open "C:\MyDownloads\binder.pdf" For Binary As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum

MsgBox "Open the folder [ C:\MyDownloads ] for the downloaded file..."
End Sub
```

The second example:

```
 Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile _
 Lib "urlmon" _
 Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
 ( _
     ByVal pCaller As Long, _
     ByVal szURL As String, _
     ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
     ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
 ) As Long



 Sub DownPDF()

Dim ss As String
Dim ts As String
ss = "https://docs.google.com/a/dink.eu/file/d/0B46Ux_7O0o-4RdefsERgaEHU2YtZXM/edit?pli=1"
ts = "c:\MyDownloads\Stryker experience binder.pdf"
URLDownloadToFile 0, ss, ts, 0, 0

End Sub
```

With normal links they works for example if I use the following link http://www.bigfoto.com/sites/main/tree-winter-xxx.JPG it works perfectly but with google drive links it doesn't. How can I do to make it work with google drive links?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this link format in the first example:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2P4BoDG6mdejjesiEEFMNHN0cFU
```

more help:
http://thebiobucket.blogspot.hu/2011/10/how-to-link-to-google-docs-for-download.html